# What does 'OPEN' mean in this curl command line?

Tags: http, curl, websocket

What does `OPEN` mean in this curl command line?

```
curl -i -H 'Content-Type: application/websocket-events' -d OPEN$'\r'$'\n' http://127.0.0.1:7999/users/socket/
```

My understanding is that `\r` and `\n` mean new line feed, but what does the `OPEN` preceding them mean? I have gone through the curl manual, but cannot find the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is posting data via curl's [`-d`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d) parameter:

> Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server

So, the data being posted is literally `OPEN\r\n`.

The command is setting the `Content-Type` to `application/websocket-events`.  See [WebSocket-Over-HTTP Protocol](https://pushpin.org/docs/protocols/websocket-over-http/) for more details about that type.  `OPEN` is the 1st command exchanged in that protocol.

Your command line translates to an HTTP request similar to this:

```
POST /users/socket/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:7999
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/websocket-events
Content-Length: 6

OPEN\r\n
```

Answer (score 2):

curl -d defines the POST data

OPEN in this case is just the specific payload you are sending